# Vsftpd и неправильное время

Tags: vsftpd

После получения файла посредством `vsftpd`, время получения стоит неверное, с отставанием на три часа. В `vsftpd.conf`, параметр `use_localtime=YES` стоит, однако время по-прежнему отстает. Подскажите куда куда копать в этой ситуации? Есть подозрение что баг.

Comment: а что показывает команда date на сервере?

Comment: показывает правильное время.

Comment: в логе vsftpd тоже правильное время.

Comment: Странно, у меня штук 10 серверов на CentOS, все с vsftpd, нет такой проблемы

Comment: у меня штук 20, начиная с 4 ветки и тоже нигде такой проблемы нет.

Comment: чудеса, однако...

Comment: дурацкий вопрос, но все же - а что выводит timedatectl? какая временная зона стоит?

Comment: не понял, что выдает ??

Comment: если date
то Tue May  2 19:15:20 MSK 2017

Comment: в CentOS есть такая команда - timedatectl. Показывает разное, включая time zone

Comment: на проблемном сервере  cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.8 (Final)  и timedatectl нет такой команды

Comment: Это в 7 есть такая команда. А что показывает `ls -l /etc/localtime`?

Comment: ls -l /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Apr 28 13:42 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Moscow

Comment: rpm -q tzdata
tzdata-2017a-1.el6.noarch

Comment: мдя, все верно. Дурацкий мой вопрос закрыт.

Comment: @KAGGDesign: если у других (или у вас спустя какое-то время) похожая проблема может возникнуть, то если вы думаете что нашли решение, то можете опубликовать его как свой ответ -- [это явно приветствуется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @jfs нет, мы не нашли решения

Comment: закоментил параметр use_localtime=YES, после рестартанул vsftpd и файл показывает правильное создания.

Comment: Тогда мало информации в самом вопросе: приведите версии ПО (если вы думаете это баг), приведите явные команды, которые вы используете чтобы время файла, системы показать) и их точный вывод (хотя бы date, ls -l файл) — также явно укажите какой вывод вы ожидали вместо получаемого. Обновите вопрос, не помещайте информацию необходимую для ответа в комментарии.